# PrimeNG Accordion duplication content issue

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I pass a list of records to my frontend, I loop through each and render an accordion for each element in the list.

The list total could be a max of 3 records.

This is my code for looping:

```
     <div class="col-lg-9" *ngFor="let template of entry.templates"
                                            style="margin-bottom:1%">

                                            <p-accordion *ngIf="template.methodCode !='NOEXIST'">
                                                <p-accordionTab header="{{template.methodCode}}">

                                                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                                    
                                                    </ng-template>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="isAdmin">
                                                        <span class="pull-right" id="SaveTemplateSpan">
                                                            <p-button label="Save Template"  styleClass="p-button-sm"
                                                                (click)="saveTemplate(template)"></p-button>
                                                        </span>                                                         
                                                    </div>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                                                        <span *ngIf="template.methodCode =='EMAIL'">
                                                            <label htmlFor="subject">Subject</label>
                                                            <input pInputText id="subject"
                                                                [(ngModel)]="template.subject" name="emailsubject"
                                                                [style]="{'width':'100%'}"  [readonly]="!isAdmin"/>
                                                            <br />
                                                        </span>
                                                        <textarea cols="1" rows="10" class="form-control"
                                                            [(ngModel)]="template.content" id="template.methodCode" name="template.methodCode" [readonly]="!isAdmin">
                                                            {{template.content}}
                                                        </textarea>
                                                    </ng-template>
                                                </p-accordionTab>
                                            </p-accordion>
                                        </div>
```

The above works and it displays the accordion(s) for each record.

If I expand the first accordion, and then expand the second accordion the content from within {{template.content}} inside TextArea of the first accordion becomes the same as the last accordion.. I'm not sure where or why this happening, can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like some code is making it behave like that. Care to share ts that handles the data and any changes of the `entry.templates` data?